# dojo dstore insert row

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

Can anyone assist me in inserting a row into a DGRID? The way I am doing it now is cloning a row, add it to the collection with the use of directives and then try to apply it to the grid. Below is the code I am using but the new row ends up getting added to the bottom instead of being inserted.

```
// Clone a row

theTable = tmxdijit.registry.byId(tableName);

firstRow = theTable.collection.data[theTable.collection.data.length-1];

firstRowDom = theTable.row(firstRow.id);

var cloneRow = json.stringify(firstRow);

cloneRow = json.parse(cloneRow);

// Get the row I want to add before

var theSelected = Object.keys(theTable.selection)[0];

if(theSelected.length > 0) {

    var theRowID = theSelected[0];

}

theTable.collection.add(cloneRow, {beforeId: theRowID});

theTable.renderArray([cloneRow]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, why don't you add the data directly to the grid store? See if this helps

```
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/example_Adding_and_deleting_data.html
```

**Adding and Deleting data**

If you want to add (remove) data programmatically, you just have to add (remove) it from the underlying data store. Since DataGrid is “DataStoreAware”, changes made to the store will be reflected automatically in the DataGrid.

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
```

.

```
<div>
    This example shows, how to add/remove rows
</div>

<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
    data-dojo-id="grid5"
    data-dojo-props="store:store3,
    query:{ name: '*' },
    rowsPerPage:20,
    clientSort:true,
    rowSelector:'20px'
    style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="200px"
                field="name">Country/Continent Name</th>
            <th width="auto"
                field="type"
                cellType="dojox.grid.cells.Select"
                options="country,city,continent"
                editable="true">Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">
    Add Row
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
        // set the properties for the new item:
        var myNewItem = {type: "country", name: "Fill this country name"};
        // Insert the new item into the store:
        // (we use store3 from the example above in this example)
        store3.newItem(myNewItem);
    </script>
</div>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">
    Remove Selected Rows
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
        // Get all selected items from the Grid:
        var items = grid5.selection.getSelected();
        if(items.length){
            // Iterate through the list of selected items.
            // The current item is available in the variable
            // "selectedItem" within the following function:
            dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem){
                if(selectedItem !== null){
                    // Delete the item from the data store:
                    store3.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                } // end if
            }); // end forEach
        } // end if
    </script>
</div>
```

.

```
@import "{{ baseUrl }}dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css";
@import "{{ baseUrl }}dojox/grid/resources/nihiloGrid.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways to handle data insertion. One is to manually add data to an array, ensure it's properly sorted, and then tell the grid to render the array. A better way is to use an OnDemandGrid with a trackable store.

For dgrid/dstore to support simple dynamic insertion of rows, make sure the store is trackable, and that data items have some unique id property:

```
var StoreClass = Memory.createSubclass(Trackable);
var store = new StoreClass({ data: whatever });
var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
    columns: { /* columns */ },
    collection: store
});
```

By default dstore assumes the id property is "id", but you can specify something else:

```
var store = new StoreClass({ idProperty: "name", data: whatever });
```

If you want the data to be sorted, a simple solution is to set a sort on the grid (the grid will sort rows in ascending order using the given property name):

```
grid.set('sort', 'name');
```

To add or remove data, use the store methods `put` and `remove`.

```
var collection = grid.get('collection');
collection.put(/* a new data item */);
collection.remove(/* a data item id */);
```

The grid will be notified of the store update and will insert or remove the rows.

The dgrid [Using Grids and Stores](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/) tutorial has more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually figured it out today by adding

var theRow = theTable.row(theSelected) ;
    theTable.renderArray([clonedRow], theRow.element) ;